# how to pass callback function in component? (laravel alpine.js)

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I make a draft implementation for my reusable **input** component.
The code below obviously throws an error.

Question is how to pass the `$event` back to **register** blade to get or log the value of the input?

**register.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <x-input onChange="(value) => {console.log('value', value)}"></x-input>
<div/>
```

**input.blade.php**

```
@props(['onChange' => 'null'])

<input x-on:change="{{ $onChange($event) }}">
```

Comment: Why not directly do that inside of the component instead of passing it ? do you use the component that dont need the onchange ?

Comment: @xenooooo its a reusable component. other page will use it aside from register page.

Comment: did you try to do something like `<x-input @change="your event here"/>`

Comment: @xenooooo i tried that but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned we could just achieve this through Alpine.Js [dispatch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch). I don't need to pass `onClick` props via Laravel component. I just simply use dispatch to listen the event (`x-on`).

What I like in this implementation is that,

- aside of event information, passing of extra data is easy
- you don't have to use Laravel props and assigned unnecessary props in the tag.

---

**register.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <x-input x-on:custom-input="console.log('your values =', $event.target.newValue)"
    ></x-input>
<div/>
```

**input.blade.php**

```
<input x-on:change="$dispatch('custom-input', { newValue: $event.target.value })">
```

---

> you can pass "key" prop to distinguish each component.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here.

First off, your markup is wrong. You have a the closing slash at the wrong end of the closing div. Should be `</div>` not `<div/>`.

Then you're using `x-on` without `x-data`. Alpine only picks up components with the x-data attribute.

Finally, events propagate automatically, so you could just listen on the parent instead:

```
{{-- register.blade.php --}}
<div x-data>
    <x-input x-on:change="console.log('value', $event.target.value)" />
</div>

{{-- input.blade.php --}}
<input {{ $attributes }}>
```

Comment: i also planned this one. but my concern of this implementation is that its straight up input passing events. To make it clear, what if we need to pass something in a callback aside from `$event`? for example `$onChange($event, 'something here')`